# Treating spaces as tabs in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I started working VS Code at work and at home recently, and have run into a weird issue; I'm not sure if it's a setting I can't find or a bug, so thought I'd ask.

I have VS code setup (in both environments) to indent 4 spaces on tab, however, on my work computer, when I navigate over the 4-space-tabs, the IDE advances the full 4 spaces, treating it like a tab but using 4 spaces. On my laptop, I have to advance space by space, and it's pretty annoying. I have the same extensions on both, none of which affect spaces as far as I know.

Any advice?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsoOG6ZeyUI :)

Comment: On your laptop, does tab work as expected for other programs such as notepad?

Comment: Yah. I've been using Atom up till now as a PHP dev, started doing Angular 2 work so figured VS Code was better for that (and it has been, barring quirks of moving to a new IDE). This seems to be a setting thing I can't figure out or a bug, not sure which.

Answer (score 0):

Look into this setting on both of your work and laptop computers
[image]

Comment: I'm using the latest version of VS Code on Windows (checked if there were any updates) and I don't see any Options modal. I checked in the preferences, but I don't see a 'Keep tabs' options in there.

Comment: I think your answer is for full Visual Studio.